# Galois Group of $x^{6}-2x^{3}-1$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, sylow-theory, galois-extensions

I was trying to compute the normal closure of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{2}}$.

I had a reallyyyy hard time proving that $x^{6}-2x^{3}-1$ is irreducible. I proved that it has no roots on $\mathbb{Q}$. Then I didn't know exactly what to do.

I used this lemma:
[$f(X^p)$ irreducible or $p$th power if $f$ irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612625/fxp-irreducible-or-pth-power-if-f-irreducible)
With the lemma, I proved that it cannot have factors of order 3, as it's polynomial is irreducible or a third power of irreducible on $\mathbb{F}_{3}[x]$ as $x^2-2x-1$ is irreducible here as it has no roots.

Then it can only has factors of order 4 and 2. If it has no factors of order 2, then it is irreducible, as if it has a factor of order 4 it has to have a factor of order 2.

To prove that it is irreducible, or it has a factor of degree $2$. Then, I used the factorization on the splitting field to see that any product of two of those linear factors is not a rational polynomial.

If there is any easier way to prove this, I would like to know. I failed horribly trying to show that it's projections on finite fields are irreducible, or shifting and using Eisenstein.

Well, then as that field contains $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{-3}]$ which is a normal extension, I know it has a normal $3$-Sylow subgroup. I know that's not abelian because it has non normal extensions (so it's group has non normal subgroups, so it's not abelian).

I had $D_{12},Q_{12}$ and $A_{4}$. I know that $A_{4}$ has more than one subgroup of order $3$ (it has four $3$-cycles). So it isn't.

But I don't know how to know if it's $D_{12}$ or $Q_{12}$. I know that if $H$ is the group that fixes $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{-3}]$, then $ G / H \cong V_{4}$ where $V_{4}$ is the Klein Group.

I feel like I need to extract more information from that field, but it's hard to find good generators or the image of the automorphisms with such $\alpha$. Computing the group of $x^{6}-3$ is way easier because $\sqrt[6]{3}$ and $i$ are more tame than this monster. Any ideas? I feel like I should be more methodic on this, but I have read Dummit section about computing Galois groups and it feels like it's very ad hoc.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762802/what-is-the-galois-group-of-ft-t6-2t3-1-over-k-mathbbq/2762844#2762844

Comment: Did you notice that the linked question applies to characteristic $p$ fields. So as such won't say anything about irreducibility over $\Bbb{Q}$, a characteristic $0$ field?

Comment: What is the field $F$ on your first line? Surely the answer depends on $F$. Presumably it is $\Bbb{Q}$ because you made that nice observation about the normal intermediate extension!

Comment: Ok. So may be you reduced it modulo three to conclude that either it is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ or it has a quadratic factor.The link seems irrelevant.

Comment: It applies to fields of characteristic p. It is right.
But the catch is the following:if it's factorizable on Q, it is on Z by Gauss lemma. Then we project to characteristic p and it is factorizable on the finite field. So if I prove that projections to that fields cannot have factors of degree 3, I have proved it for Q too. But I forgot to write that on the mathstackexchange post. I will correct it.
@Dave. Thanks. I didn't thought about searching with t instead of x as a variable. Regardless, I don't see on that link neither a way to prove irreducibility nor why the group isn't Q12.

Comment: For the question of irreducibility, which @Dave passes over in silence in his linked answer, I think you need do only this: Let $\xi$ be a root of $f(x)=x^6-2x^3-1$. We are asking whether $[\Bbb Q(\xi):\Bbb Q]=6$. You know that $\xi^3=1+\sqrt2$, and you use the fact that the unit group of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2\,]$ is generated by $-1$ and $1+\sqrt2$: the latter is a primitive unit of the field, and therefore has no cube roots in the field. So $g(x)=x^3-(1+\sqrt2\,)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)$. So by multiplicativity of degree, your big degree is six, the polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: The unit grpup of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ are the elements with field norm 1. So, it is generated by (-1) and $1+\sqrt{2}$  as a multiplicative group. But why primitive units have no cube root? -1 has it on $\mathbb{Z}$, hasn't it? But yeah, if it has not one on $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ it won't have it on the rationals either, and so that degree 3 polynomial wilñ be irreducible. And so on the original polynomial ring the polynomial of degree 6 will be irreducible. But I don't know why $1+\sqrt{2}$ has not roots on that field. I guess I could guess I could prove it by contradiction.

Comment: I re-read Dave's answer. We know it is a subgroup of order 12 of S6, and it contains a 6-cycle. But how do we know the quaternions are not one of those? Using the knowledge of the entire subgroups structure of S6 feels more lile usimg group pokedex than I am comfortable with.  Anyway, I will continue trying. If I come up with an elegant solution I will write an answer here.

Comment: Thanks dave. After reading your answer I looked for this:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233939/dicyclic-group-as-subgroup-of-s-6
It took me 3 pages to write all the computations, but I proved that statement so I will use it more often. In short, if a Galois extension of order 12 has a Galois subextension of order 4 and it has some non Galois subextension, then it has to have $D_{12}$ as Galois group.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha_i$ be the roots of $x^{6}-2x^{3}-1$.

Let $\omega$ be a root of $x^2 - x + 1$ so that $\omega^3 = -1$.

- $\alpha_1 = \sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{2}}$
- $\alpha_2 = \omega \sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{2}} = \omega \alpha_1$
- $\alpha_3 = \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{2}} = \omega^2 \alpha_1$
- $\alpha_4 = \sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{2}} = -\omega^2/\alpha_1$
- $\alpha_5 = \omega \sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{2}} = 1/\alpha_1$
- $\alpha_6 = \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{2}} = \omega/\alpha_1$

Thus $\mathbb Q(\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\alpha_{3},\alpha_{4},\alpha_{5},\alpha_{6}) = \mathbb Q(\omega,\alpha_1)$. And $[\mathbb Q(\omega):\mathbb Q] = 2$, $[\mathbb Q(\alpha_1):\mathbb Q] = 6$ so the composite has degree 6 or 12.

We can produce 12 distinct automorphisms based on mapping $\alpha_1$ to any other $\alpha$ and $\omega$ to $\omega$ or $\omega^2$.

This forms a 6-cycle with an inversion map. This is the group $D_{12}$

Comment: $2$ and $6$ aren't coprime !?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks, removed